# error in removing super sets in matlab?

Tags: matlab

guys i have a 1D cell array named as `OccursTogether` having values for each pair what i want to do is to remove all the super sets and keep there subsets only but the output i get is not what i want, the code i used is as follows:

```
[ii, jj] = ndgrid(1:numel(OccursTogether));
s = cellfun(@(x,y) all(ismember(x,y)), OccursTogether(ii), OccursTogether(jj));
s = triu(s,1); %// count each pair just once, and remove self-pairs
result = OccursTogether(~any(s,1));
```

my input is as follows:

```
{14}
{9 14 17}
{16}
{11}
{11 16}
{5}
{5 16}
{1}
{4 11 14}
```

now what i want as output is `{1 5 14 11 16}` but the above code returns empty`{}` output.

can anyone please help in getting desired output

Comment: I see that you are trying to implement a loop to do ismember on every cell with every other cell; this is going to be quite computationally intensive, I would suggest converting all numbers in the cell to a vector and use the histc (histogram) which is fast efficient way of counting occurrences of each element, you can then remove the elements where count is less than 1. Otherwise, you could try merging cells and use intersect, which would also be faster

Comment: by the way, I am not sue if you can run ismember the way you are looping it...

Comment: @qmeeeeeee i don't want to count the occurences and on the other hand it is no necessary that always the count will be less than 1 for the element that is to me removed. i know it is computationally expensive but at this point i am not concerned with that. loop helps to traverse and compare each element with every other cell values.

Comment: @qmeeeeeee if u have a better idea than `ismember` please share with me

Comment: I assume you want the elements in the cell that occurs more than once?

Comment: @qmeeeeeee actually i want to keep the subsets and remove the supersets for example from above example keep `14` and delete its super set `9 14 17` same as this keep `11` and remove `11 16`

Comment: I see, would it then be logical if you start by taking all cells with length 1 (i.e. 1 number in it), see if other subsets contains this number, if it does, remove it. Move on to all cells with length 2, do the same thing until you have no more cells to remove?

Comment: @qmeeeeeee yes it is possible but i am unable to implement this logic in matlab code.